# Xlsx file not supported anymore. Solution to setup a new BW2 project?

Tags: python, brightway

I've resumed calculations on BW2 this week after a few months of break and my old notebooks don't work anymore due to the change in XLRD, which doesn't read xlsx anymore (if I understand [this post](https://exerror.com/xlrd-biffh-xlrderror-excel-xlsx-file-not-supported/) correctly).

I'm starting a new project:

```
bw.projects.set_current("MyNewProject")
bw.bw2setup()
```

And I get this in return:

```
XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported
```

If I understand correctly, it comes from the *init* of bw2io. Where I found:

```
def get_sheet(path, name):
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
    return wb.sheet_by_name(name)
```

I suppose I should replace

```
xlrd.open_workbook(path)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Don't use `xld` or work with the ancient `xls` format that was abandoned 15 years ago. Excel's format is `xlsx`, introduced in 2006. There's absolutely no reason or benefit in using the ancient format. No compatibility reasons or benefits. No size or performance gains (xlsx is smaller and faster). Cloud services like Google Docs or Office 365 won't work with `xls` unless you use a paid subscription

Comment: Did you try to work with `openpyxl`? That's "Solution 3" in the post you mentioned.

Comment: Discarding `xlrd` and `xls` in general is actually the only solution. There are several libraries that work with `xlsx` like `openpyxl`, `xlsxwriter` or Pandas

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think you misunderstood the question. The asker has xlsx files, but those are not longer supported by `xlrd`.

Comment: @Matthias I understood the issue very well. `xlrd` shouldn't be used in the first place

Comment: OK, thank you for your responses. In the _init_ of bw2io, I found the issue:

def get_sheet(path, name):
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
    return wb.sheet_by_name(name)

I suppose I should replace xlrd.open_workbook(path). Any advice?

Comment: (I updated the question for clearer reading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [2.0 release](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html) of [xlrd](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) removed support for `.xlsx` files. `bw2io` was using `xlrd`, but as of the [0.8 release](https://brightway.groups.io/g/updates/message/4) uses `openpyxl`. So, you can solve this problem by either explicitly forcing an install of `xlrd` < 2.0, or by updating your `bw2io` library.

Note that if you are using anaconda, you might need to start a new environment using Python 3.8 or 3.9 to get the latest version of `bw2io` to install correctly. There is no reason not to have the latest Python release (3.9 as of this post) installed, so this is probably best practice anyway.

Comment: Perfect! I had updated BW2 and was surprised that it did not integrate the xlrd modification.It is now clear that this was cause fof my old version of Python. Thks